# Linear optimization in R, Stigler diet problem

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

Has anyone tried to replicate [The Stigler Diet problen](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop#data) in R?

So far this is what I have:

```
library(lpSolve)
library(linprog)

# where d is the nutrients data frame found in the above link

f.obj_ <- d$`1939 price (cents) `
f.con_ <- matrix(c( d$Calories,
                    d$`Protein (g)`,
                    d$`Calcium (g)`,                  
                    d$`Iron (mg)`,
                    d$`Vitamin A (IU)`,
                    d$`Thiamine (mg)`  ,
                    d$`Riboflavin (mg)` ,
                    d$`Niacin (mg)`,
                    d$`Ascorbic Acid (mg)`), nrow = 9, byrow = TRUE)
f.dir <- rep(">=", 9)

f.rhs <- c(3.0, 70.0, 0.8, 12.0, 5.0, 1.8, 2.7, 18.0, 75.0)

lp("min", f.obj_, f.con_, f.dir, f.rhs)
# returns: 0.7164608
```

My guess is that the Python code uses a different optimizer than the one from lpSolve (Glop method). Is there a Glop optimizer in R that allows me to replicate the results from the Py code?

Comment: I think you need to set the objective to be 1 for all foods. At least that is what they do in the post you linked to. "The nutritional data below is per dollar, not per unit..." Also, you need to multiply the objective by 365.25 to get to the $39.69

Comment: You are absolutely right `f.obj_ <- rep(1, 77)` instead of using `f.obj_ <- d$`1939 price (cents) ` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I had not yet replicated this, I had been planning to do so for a long time. Now your question was a good reason and got me away from Netflix.

Here is a solution using `lpSolveAPI`:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
# minimum requirements
requirements <- c(
    calories=3, protein=70, calcium=0.8, iron=12,
    vit_a=5, vit_b1=1.8, vit_b2=2.7,
    vit_b3=18, vit_c=75
)

# nutrition data
dat <- data.frame(
    commodity=c(
        "Wheat Flour (Enriched)", "Macaroni", "Wheat Cereal (Enriched)", 
        "Corn Flakes", "Corn Meal", "Hominy Grits", "Rice", "Rolled Oats", 
        "White Bread (Enriched)", "Whole Wheat Bread", "Rye Bread", 
        "Pound Cake", "Soda Crackers", "Milk", "Evaporated Milk (can)", 
        "Butter", "Oleomargarine", "Eggs", "Cheese (Cheddar)", "Cream", 
        "Peanut Butter", "Mayonnaise", "Crisco", "Lard", "Sirloin Steak", 
        "Round Steak", "Rib Roast", "Chuck Roast", "Plate", "Liver (Beef)", 
        "Leg of Lamb", "Lamb Chops (Rib)", "Pork Chops", "Pork Loin Roast", 
        "Bacon", "Ham, smoked", "Salt Pork", "Roasting Chicken", 
        "Veal Cutlets", "Salmon, Pink (can)", "Apples", "Bananas", 
        "Lemons", "Oranges", "Green Beans", "Cabbage", "Carrots", 
        "Celery", "Lettuce", "Onions", "Potatoes", "Spinach", "Sweet Potatoes", 
        "Peaches (can)", "Pears (can)", "Pineapple (can)", "Asparagus (can)", 
        "Green Beans (can)", "Pork and Beans (can)", "Corn (can)", 
        "Peas (can)", "Tomatoes (can)", "Tomato Soup (can)", "Peaches, Dried", 
        "Prunes, Dried", "Raisins, Dried", "Peas, Dried", "Lima Beans, Dried", 
        "Navy Beans, Dried", "Coffee", "Tea", "Cocoa", "Chocolate", 
        "Sugar", "Corn Syrup", "Molasses", "Strawberry Preserves"
    ), 
    unit=c(
        "10 lb.", "1 lb.", "28 oz.", "8 oz.", "1 lb.", "24 oz.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", 
        "1 qt.", "14.5 oz.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 doz.", "1 lb.", 
        "1/2 pt.", "1 lb.", "1/2 pt.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", 
        "16 oz.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 doz.", "1 doz.", "1 lb.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 bunch", "1 stalk", "1 head", "1 lb.", "15 lb.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "No. 2 1/2", "No. 2 1/2", "No. 2 1/2", 
        "No. 2", "No. 2", "16 oz.", "No. 2", "No. 2", "No. 2", "10 1/2 oz.", 
        "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "15 oz.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", "1 lb.", 
        "1/4 lb.", "8 oz.", "8 oz.", "10 lb.", "24 oz.", "18 oz.", 
        "1 lb."
    ), 
    price=c(    
        36, 14.1, 24.2, 7.1, 4.6, 8.5, 7.5, 7.1, 7.9, 9.1, 
        9.1, 24.8, 15.1, 11, 6.7, 30.8, 16.1, 32.6, 24.2, 14.1, 17.9, 
        16.7, 20.3, 9.8, 39.6, 36.4, 29.2, 22.6, 14.6, 26.8, 27.6, 
        36.6, 30.7, 24.2, 25.6, 27.4, 16, 30.3, 42.3, 13, 4.4, 6.1, 
        26, 30.9, 7.1, 3.7, 4.7, 7.3, 8.2, 3.6, 34, 8.1, 5.1, 16.8, 
        20.4, 21.3, 27.7, 10, 7.1, 10.4, 13.8, 8.6, 7.6, 15.7, 9, 
        9.4, 7.9, 8.9, 5.9, 22.4, 17.4, 8.6, 16.2, 51.7, 13.7, 13.6, 
        20.5
    ), 
    calories=c(44.7, 11.6, 11.8, 11.4, 36, 28.6, 21.2, 25.3, 15, 12.2, 
        12.4, 8, 12.5, 6.1, 8.4, 10.8, 20.6, 2.9, 7.4, 3.5, 15.7, 
        8.6, 20.1, 41.7, 2.9, 2.2, 3.4, 3.6, 8.5, 2.2, 3.1, 3.3, 
        3.5, 4.4, 10.4, 6.7, 18.8, 1.8, 1.7, 5.8, 5.8, 4.9, 1, 2.2, 
        2.4, 2.6, 2.7, 0.9, 0.4, 5.8, 14.3, 1.1, 9.6, 3.7, 3, 2.4, 
        0.4, 1, 7.5, 5.2, 2.3, 1.3, 1.6, 8.5, 12.8, 13.5, 20, 17.4, 
        26.9, 0, 0, 8.7, 8, 34.9, 14.7, 9, 6.4
    ), 
    protein=c(
        1411, 418, 377, 252, 
        897, 680, 460, 907, 488, 484, 439, 130, 288, 310, 422, 9, 
        17, 238, 448, 49, 661, 18, 0, 0, 166, 214, 213, 309, 404, 
        333, 245, 140, 196, 249, 152, 212, 164, 184, 156, 705, 27, 
        60, 21, 40, 138, 125, 73, 51, 27, 166, 336, 106, 138, 20, 
        8, 16, 33, 54, 364, 136, 136, 63, 71, 87, 99, 104, 1367, 
        1055, 1691, 0, 0, 237, 77, 0, 0, 0, 11
    ), 
    calcium=c(
        2, 0.7, 14.4, 0.1, 
        1.7, 0.8, 0.6, 5.1, 2.5, 2.7, 1.1, 0.4, 0.5, 10.5, 15.1, 
        0.2, 0.6, 1, 16.4, 1.7, 1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 
        0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 6.8, 
        0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 1.1, 3.7, 4, 2.8, 3, 1.1, 3.8, 1.8, 0, 2.7, 
        0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 2, 4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 1.7, 2.5, 2.5, 
        4.2, 3.7, 11.4, 0, 0, 3, 1.3, 0, 0.5, 10.3, 0.4
    ), 
    iron=c(
        365, 54, 175, 56, 99, 80, 41, 341, 115, 125, 82, 31, 50, 18, 9, 3, 
        6, 52, 19, 3, 48, 8, 0, 0, 34, 32, 33, 46, 62, 139, 20, 15, 
        30, 37, 23, 31, 26, 30, 24, 45, 36, 30, 14, 18, 80, 36, 43, 
        23, 22, 59, 118, 138, 54, 10, 8, 8, 12, 65, 134, 16, 45, 
        38, 43, 173, 154, 136, 345, 459, 792, 0, 0, 72, 39, 0, 74, 244, 7
    ), 
    vit_a=c(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 30.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18.9, 0, 16.8, 
        26, 44.2, 55.8, 18.6, 28.1, 16.9, 0, 2.7, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
        0, 0.4, 0, 169.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 3.5, 7.3, 
        17.4, 0, 11.1, 69, 7.2, 188.5, 0.9, 112.4, 16.6, 6.7, 918.4, 
        290.7, 21.5, 0.8, 2, 16.3, 53.9, 3.5, 12, 34.9, 53.2, 57.9, 
        86.8, 85.7, 4.5, 2.9, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2
    ), 
    vit_b1=c(
        55.4, 3.2, 14.4, 13.5, 17.4, 10.6, 2, 37.1, 13.8, 13.9, 9.9, 2.8, 
        0, 4, 3, 0, 0.2, 2.8, 0.8, 0.6, 9.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 2.1, 2.5, 
        0, 1, 0.9, 6.4, 2.8, 1.7, 17.4, 18.2, 1.8, 9.9, 1.4, 0.9, 
        1.4, 1, 3.6, 2.5, 0.5, 3.6, 4.3, 9, 6.1, 1.4, 1.8, 4.7, 29.4, 
        5.7, 8.4, 0.5, 0.8, 2.8, 1.4, 1.6, 8.3, 1.6, 4.9, 3.4, 3.5, 
        1.2, 3.9, 6.3, 28.7, 26.9, 38.4, 4, 0, 2, 0.9, 0, 0, 1.9, 0.2
    ), 
    vit_b2=c(
        33.3, 1.9, 8.8, 2.3, 7.9, 1.6, 4.8, 8.9, 8.5, 6.4, 3, 
        3, 0, 16, 23.5, 0.2, 0, 6.5, 10.3, 2.5, 8.1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
        2.9, 2.4, 2, 4, 0, 50.8, 3.9, 2.7, 2.7, 3.6, 1.8, 3.3, 1.8, 
        1.8, 2.4, 4.9, 2.7, 3.5, 0, 1.3, 5.8, 4.5, 4.3, 1.4, 3.4, 
        5.9, 7.1, 13.8, 5.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 2.1, 4.3, 7.7, 2.7, 2.5, 
        2.5, 2.4, 4.3, 4.3, 1.4, 18.4, 38.2, 24.6, 5.1, 2.3, 11.9, 
        3.4, 0, 0, 7.5, 0.4
    ), 
    vit_b3=c(
        441, 68, 114, 68, 106, 110, 60, 64, 
        126, 160, 66, 17, 0, 7, 11, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 471, 0, 0, 5, 
        69, 87, 0, 120, 0, 316, 86, 54, 60, 79, 71, 50, 0, 68, 57, 
        209, 5, 28, 4, 10, 37, 26, 89, 9, 11, 21, 198, 33, 83, 31, 
        5, 7, 17, 32, 56, 42, 37, 36, 67, 55, 65, 24, 162, 93, 217, 
        50, 42, 40, 14, 0, 5, 146, 3
    ), 
    vit_c=c(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 177, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 525, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 544, 498, 952, 
        1998, 862, 5369, 608, 313, 449, 1184, 2522, 2755, 1912, 196, 
        81, 399, 272, 431, 0, 218, 370, 1253, 862, 57, 257, 136, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
rownames(dat) <- dat[,"commodity"]
dat[,"commodity"] <- NULL

# formulate problem
lprec <- lpSolveAPI::make.lp(ncol=nrow(dat))
lpSolveAPI::lp.control(lprec, sense='min')
lpSolveAPI::set.objfn(lprec, rep(1, nrow(dat)))
for (req in names(requirements)) {
    lpSolveAPI::add.constraint(lprec, dat[,req], ">=", requirements[req])
}

# solve
status <- lpSolveAPI::solve.lpExtPtr(lprec)
stopifnot(status==0) 
message("cost per year ($): ", lpSolveAPI::get.objective(lprec)*365.25)
diet <- lpSolveAPI::get.variables(lprec)
names(diet) <- rownames(dat)
diet <- diet[diet>0]
```

I think the problem were be more instructive if the nutrient data would be per unit and not per dollar.